# How to include configured claims in ADFS (as IDP) metadata.xml or know them in advance (before the profile object returned)?

Tags: node.js, metadata, adfs3.0, idp, passport-saml

I am using Saml SSO with ADFS (as IDP), in ADFS UI I configured all the needed data for my SP (third party) application including roles (claims).
Now in ADFS there is an option to copy a link of the federation metadata xml with all of my configured data.
My problem is: in this metadata xml link ADFS gave me I can’t find the roles (claims) that I defined (I can see them in the profile respond object that returned after a successful authentication but not in the metadata xml).
My questions are:
1.  Does the ADFS metadata xml should include my claims?
2.  If yes, can you explain me please how can I include them?
3.  Else, can you suggest a way for me to know which claims (keys) are going to return in the profile object in front?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. No - metadata is server specific not user specific
2. You only get the claims you configure on ADFS